# How do I set the 'default' focused node in JavaFX 2?

Tags: focus, javafx-2

I'm trying to set a particular `Node` in my `Stage` to be the 'default' keyboard focused Node.

Let me explain: I start out by calling `node.requestFocus()` on a focusable `Node`, and then I disable and then eventually re-enable the root of the entire `Node` graph.  When this is done, I find that the keyboard focus has moved to some other focusable node.   I'm guessing that the other node is the "default" focusable node, i.e. the `Node` that gets focus when coming back from a disabled state where no `Node` can be focused.  Unfortunately, this is not the node that I want to have focus!

Does anyone know of a way to control which node will get the keyboard focus in a situation like this?  Actually, it would even be fine if there was a way to make JavaFX just remember the previously focused node and go back to it.

Comment: As far as I remember, there is no such API, you can file an RFE in javafx jira about this, or try to find, may there is already exists such one.

Comment: Couldn't you simply call your `node.requestFocus()` again after the function that disables and re-enables your nodes?  You could even save the node that needs focus somewhere and use that reference to `requestFocus`.  You could disable tabbed order as well using `setFocusTraversable(false)` to the items not needed, which could help.

Comment: @blo0p3r:  this is pretty good idea, except that `node.requestFocus()` also requests focus for the `Stage` that contains the `Node`, which could lead to background windows popping to the front when we change disable/re-enable.   Still, I'm sure there's ways I could work around that too...

Comment: @Xanatos just so I understant, you would want to re-enable a stage that would be in the background, and by calling this re-enable function, wouldn't want it to come back to the front?

Comment: @blo0p3r: not specifically; it's more that if a background Stage ever did get re-enabled (say, a long running process finished or something) I wouldn't want that to unavoidably bring the stage to the front.  We enabled/disable stages all the time in our application, so having a "toFront" happen as a side effect of "setEnabled" would be undesirable.

Comment: So you would have to check to see if the scene has focus before giving focus to the node.  Never tried something of the sort.  Will look into it.